# How can we convert string data into datatable?

Tags: c#, parsing, datatable

I need to convert string data into datatable.

In a single string am getting this whole data.

```
sffa

S.No  Name   Address  Company
----  ----   -------  -------
 1     xxx    yyy     zzz
 2     vvv    nnn     dsd
```

Below is the code to get the above data

```
public string Read()
    {
        if (!tcpSocket.Connected) return null;
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        do
        {
            ParseTelnet(sb);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeOutMs);
        } while (tcpSocket.Available > 0);
        var strResult=sb.ToString();
        return strResult;
    }
```

I want S.No, Name, Address, Company as Column and and those value should be in the appropriate columns.

Please help and Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please share a string in which you get all data.?

Comment: What is the delimiter? Multiple spaces or a tab?

Comment: Please see the updated question

Comment: @Raj: so what is the delimiter?

Comment: @Raj Is "sffa" part of the data? What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        string data = @"S.No  Name   Address  Company
----  ----   -------  -------
 1     xxx    yyy     zzz
 2     vvv    nnn     dsd";

        var lines = data.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None);
        var lengths = lines[1] + " "; //We'll think the dashes are the column markers.

        var insideColumn = false;
        int start = 0;
        var columns = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < lengths.Length; i++) {
            if (insideColumn && lengths[i] == ' ') {
                insideColumn = false;
                columns.Add(Tuple.Create(start, i));
            }
            if (!insideColumn && lengths[i] == '-') {
                insideColumn = true;
                start = i;
            }
        }

        var headers = new List<string>(columns.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.Count; i++) {
            headers.Add(lines[0].Substring(columns[i].Item1, columns[i].Item2 - columns[i].Item1).Trim());
        }

        var table = new List<Dictionary<string,string>>();
        for (int i = 2; i < lines.Length; i++) {
            var record = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            var line = lines[i].PadRight(lengths.Length);
            for (int j = 0; j < columns.Count; j++) {
                record[headers[j]] = line.Substring(columns[j].Item1, columns[j].Item2 - columns[j].Item1).Trim();
            }
            table.Add(record);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that tab is the delimiter:

```
IEnumerable<string[]> data = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(line => line.Split('\t'))
    .Where(fields => fields.Length == 4)
    .ToList();
DataTable table = new DataTable();
foreach(string col in data.First())
    table.Columns.Add(col);
foreach (string[] fields in data.Skip(1))
    table.Rows.Add(fields);
```

If the delimiter is one or multiple spaces and the values itself cannot contains spaces:

```
IEnumerable<string[]> data = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(line => line.Trim().Split(new char[]{}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .Where(fields => fields.Length == 4)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. I have tried your code but in data variable I couldn't see any value. Checking in debug mode Datacount = 0. Please advice.

Comment: I want S.No, Name, Address, Company as Column and and those value should be in the appropriate columns.

Comment: @Ra: you still haven't mentioned the delimiter. It doesn't seem to be the tab character. So what it is?

Comment: Delimiter is space between the each value in the column.

Comment: @raw: i strongly doubt it. What if the value itself contains a space? However, edited my answer.